# How to scrape multiple websites using Rcrawler in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcrawler

I've noticed we don't have many questions here about Rcrawler, and I thought it's a great tool to scrape website. However, I have a problem telling it to scrape multiple websites as it can only do 3 currently. Please let me know if anyone has experience with this issue. Thanks.

I've tried putting all URLs in a list/vector, but it still doesn't do it. Here are my scraping codes to get the title, description, and keywords of the websites.

```
Rcrawler(Website = c("http://www.amazon.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.wsj.com"),
 no_cores = 3, no_conn = 3, MaxDepth = 0, 
ExtractXpathPat = c('/html/head/title', '//meta[@name="description"]/@content', '//meta[@name="keywords"]/@content'),
 PatternsName = c("Title", "Description", "Keywords"), saveOnDisk = FALSE)
```

If I have more than 3 websites, it will give me this error:

```
Error in Rcrawler(Website = c("http://www.amazon.com", "www.yahoo.com",  : 
  object 'getNewM' not found
```

Comment: You may need to wrap your code in some function and pass it to a framework that can handle multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# Create vector
mylist <- c("http://www.amazon.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.wsj.com")
# Create the for statement
for (i in mylist)
{ 
  #print(i)
  webpage <- read_html(i)
  print(webpage)

}
```

Or, load each page into a list and parse the list.  Finally, you may consider saving your results to a CSV.  You should know, scraping lots of different web pages will almost certainly product very different results.  I can certainy understand why a person would want to loop through different URLs of the same site, but I'm not sure what you will gain by looping through different URLs of different sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would work in theory, but you can try creating many calls to R crawler.
For example in a while loop:

```
a <- list()

Rcrawler_function <- function(no_conn,no_cores,MaxDepth ,Obeyrobots,saveOnDisk,ExtractXpath)
{
  x <- 1
  while(x < 5)
  {
    tryCatch( expr = {

  Rcrawler(df$gen_link[x],no_conn = no_conn,no_cores = no_cores,MaxDepth = MaxDepth,Obeyrobots = Obeyrobots,saveOnDisk = saveOnDisk,ExtractXpathPat = ExtractXpath)
   assign("DATA",DATA,envir = globalenv())
     a[[x]] <<- DATA
    x = x+1


    }
  , error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
  }
}

Rcrawler_function(4,4,0,T,F,"body")
```